# Getting Artifact files for Maven EnforcerRule

Tags: java, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm writing an [`EnforcerRule`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) for `maven-enforcer-plugin` that needs to look at the jars that are transitive dependencies of the project.

In the code below, I'm getting the bits and pieces that I need, then getting all the dependencies, and for each with packaging=jar, I do some work.

```
public void execute(EnforcerRuleHelper helper) throws EnforcerRuleException {
  ... // Configuration wrangling

  Log log = helper.getLog();
  MavenProject project;
  try {
    project = (MavenProject) helper.evaluate("${project}");
  } catch (ExpressionEvaluationException ex) {
    throw new EnforcerRuleException(
        "Project unavailable " + ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
  }

  ArtifactResolver resolver;
  try {
    resolver = (ArtifactResolver)
        helper.getComponent(ArtifactResolver.class);
  } catch (ComponentLookupException ex) {
    throw new EnforcerRuleException(
        "Component unavailable " + ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  ImmutableSet<Artifact> allArtifacts = ImmutableSet.<Artifact>builder()
      .add(project.getArtifact())
      .addAll(project.getArtifacts())
      .build();

  JarChecker jarChecker = new JarChecker(log, p, resolver);

  for (Artifact art : allArtifacts) {
    String artType = art.getType();
    if ("jar".equals(artType)) {
      try {
        jarChecker.checkJar(art);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

My jar checker does the following

```
File f = art.getFile();
if (f == null) {
  throw new EnforcerRuleException(
      "Cannot check artifact " + artToString(art)
      + " since it has not been packaged.");
}
// Do stuff with f.
```

Unfortunately, `f` is null when I run `mvn package` on my test-project.

Is there some way to specify that a rule should run post dependency collection and resolution a la `@Mojo(requireDependencyCollection=Scope.COMPILE, requireDependencyResolution=Scope.COMPILE)`?

Is there a better way to express, in an enforcer rule, "for each file in each dependee jar, ..."?